# Can Keycloak Persist Identity Provider Sessions for AD users

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, saml

We have users who login as Keycloak users and also users who login as AD users (we have created a saml Indentity Provider in Keycloak).

When logging in as a Keycloak user, the user can check ‘remember me’. This enables the user to entirely close the browser and when they open the browser (and open the login page) the user is still logged in. I imagine a persistent cookie is used.

When logging in as an AD user, the user has to reenter their credentials after entirely closing the browser.

Is there a way that Keycloak can persist sessions for AD users who have logged in through AD through a saml Identity Provider which has been configured in Keycloak? I know that AD has a ‘Stay Signed In’ option in their authentication flow. What I’m asking is whether it is possible for Keycloak to persist a session so that the AD authentication flow doesn’t even have to be entered for users who have previously logged in.

Comment: is keycloak acting as a SAML IdP or SAML SP? How it federates with AD?

Comment: Keycloak is acting as a SAML SP. We have added a SAMLv2.0 Identity Provider to Keycloak, with config pointing to an Azure AD enterprise app (with SAML config). The AAD is the IdP.

Comment: I believe applying same cookie policy to both types of users (AD and keycloak) will solve the issue. because ultimately its keycloak whos going to provide the session and issue its own cookie.

Comment: Can you say a little more Bhushan? I've observed that Keycloak sets the “KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY” cookie on login and that: it is a persistent cookie when "keep me logged in" is checked (when logging in as a keycloak user) and a session cookie when "keep me logged in" is unchecked (when logging in as a keycloak user) or after an AD login (through the Keycloak SAML Identity Provider). I can't see where I'd set a "same cookie policy". We're using Keycloak 6.0.1.

Comment: If AD user gets authenticated (with SAML) and then keycloak is issuing its own cookie (which is persistent cookie), then the cookie policy is already same for both types of users. Once the keycloak issues its own cookie, it should not matter whether the user is from keycloak's local db or from AD. What is the exact problem here?

Comment: I am trying to find a solution for the same problem, we’re you able to get this working?